# Pluggable boards joinery

Tags: joinery, plywood, knockdown

I'm looking for a pluggable (fast assembly) way to join two plywood boards. I liked the method that the company Tylko uses. I wonder if parts for such joinery are freely available on the market. What is this type of joinery called?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to WSE. Your video link does not work

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. This is a type of knockdown (sometimes shortened to K/D or KD) joinery. You'll find a few previous Q&As here on this which give similar (or at least alternative) options if you try the internal search.

Comment: Just to confirm one thing, you are looking for fast assembly/reassembly and not fast *installation* yes?

Comment: @Graphus yes. The main goal is to invest more time in the production phase to make it easy to assemble/disassemble and also to modularize the project.

Comment: @Ashlar thanks for checking. Unfortunately, I couldn't fix that. Removed the link completely. Hope it's clear from just observing the picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm looking for a pluggable (fast assembly) way to join two plywood boards... What is this type of joinery called?

The general category of hardware that you're looking for is known as *knockdown connectors* or *KD hardware*. Many different types are available depending on what you want to connect and what tools you have available.

> I liked the method that the company Tylko uses. I wonder if parts for such joinery are freely available on the market.

The specific connector in the photo look like it's part of the [INVISO system](http://siso.dk/products/knock-down-fittings/kd-systems/invisio-kd-system) from the Danish company [SISO](http://siso.dk/about). Specifically, it looks like one of the [single clip](http://siso.dk/products/knock-down-fittings/kd-systems/invisio-kd-system/invisio-single-clip-4061--f-19mm-panel--non-locking) panel connectors.

The web site doesn't display prices for these connectors, so it's not clear whether they're available for sale in small enough quantities to make sense for a typical home woodworker, but I expect you can buy them if you don't mind buying some minimum quantity. If that doesn't work out, there are lots of other connector systems that do pretty much the same thing. Anyone who has ever assembled an IKEA product will be familiar with [cam lock fittings](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DLWC7RP) that work with shoulder screws to lock panels together. There are also some KD fittings that are meant to be used with the Festool Domino joiner.